# Authenticate multiple models in passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

so for the past hour I've been searching the way to authenticate multiple models in a login in passport.js with no avail.
My app has 2 models, teacher and student, I wanted to make a login page to check it is teacher or student, then log them in, I tried to serialize and deserialize those two models in app.js, but it seems like it doesn't know which one to authenticate, is there any way I can do this?

Edit:
I have a position field in both my student and teacher's collection, 1 for student and 2 for teacher.
It seems that the passport.use() is overwritten by the second passport.use() call, as the result, I'm only able to login via Student, and if I flip them, I can login to Teacher.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new localStrategyTeacher (Teacher.authenticate()));
passport.use(new localStrategyStudent (Student.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    let type;
    if (user.position === 1) {
        type = 'student';
    } else  {
        type = 'teacher';
    }

    done(null, {id: user.id, type});
});

passport.deserializeUser((key, done) => {
    if(key.type === 'student'){
        Student.findById(key.id, function(err, user) {
          done(err, user);
        });
      } else {
        Teacher.findById(key.id, function(err, user) {
          done(err, user);
        });
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I don't have a score high enough to make a comment :).  Without a larger snippet it is a bit hard to tell, but it seems like the following passport issue may provide the answer you are looking for

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/50

And your passport.serializeUser and deserializeUser would need to be a bit more complicated, example. (not tested sorry)

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  let type = user.isTeacher() ? 'teacher' : 'student';
  done(null, { id: user.id, type: type});
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(data, done) {
  if(data.type === 'student'){
    Student.findById(data.id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  } else{
    Teacher.findById(data.id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't work on my end, I've updated my question.

Comment: In what way did it not work?  Looking at your update I can see an error in the searlizer. The last line should be `done(null, {id: user.id, type:type});`